# How to uncheck a checkbox in angular2

Tags: html, checkbox, angular

I have code in the HTML file that looks like this

```
 <tr *ngFor="#tradeSource of tradeSources">
     <td>
         <label>
         <input type="checkbox" ngControl="tradeSource"    [(ngModel)]="tradeSource['checked']"/>
         </label>
     </td>           
     <td>{{tradeSource.blah}}</td>
     <td>{{tradeSource.blah}}</td>
     <td>{{tradeSource.blah}}</td>
</tr>
```

A user can check the check box then click a "Process" button that will run some code, after this code has run I would like to uncheck this checkbox. Ive tried code like

```
this.tradeSources[i]['checked'] = false
```

But this isnt working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you should rather try is:

```
this.tradeSources[i]['checked'] = false
```

**Edit**

I think that your problem is because you have the same name for each control of checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" ngControl="tradeSource"  
       [(ngModel)]="tradeSource.checked"/>
```

If you remove the `ngControl` attribute, it works:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="tradeSource.checked"/>
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/FdPHpOTSySkg2gLWjo7a?p=preview.

If you really want an `ngControl` you could define it this way:

```
<tr *ngFor="#tradeSource of tradeSources;#i=index">
  <td>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" [ngControl]="'trade'+i" 
             [(ngModel)]="tradeSource.checked"/>
    </label>
  </td>           
  (...)
</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry this is what it already is in the code, I made a typo in my post

Comment: Okay. In fact, it's because of your `ngControl` that have the same name for each checkbox...

Comment: This works perfectly, the solution for keeping an ngControl works too, thanks

Comment: plnkr is broken

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason this is not working, and which should probably also throw an error in your console, is the usage of unbinded `ngControl`. It should be enough to just do:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="tradeSource['checked']">
```